# How to compare laptop sound card/device with a desktop motherboard sound device using specifications?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, audio, sound-cards

I want to buy a budget motherboard (B450 or B520) but the most of them have **Realtek® ALC892/ALC897 Codec** mentioned in them. You can consider *MSI A520M-A PRO Gaming* or *MSI B450M PRO-VDH MAX Gaming* for example.

I read a lot about this and people said it is an old codec and *sound quality is poor*. If you need good audio, at least choose ALC1200 or 1220 Codec. Motherboards that have these codecs are *not* in my budget.

Now, I can't imagine how bad is the audio quality is going to be. Sadly, I have to somehow determine it before buying it.

---

I have a Dell 7570 i7 Laptop that I bought in 2017. I never faced any audio problem with it. The quality is fine for me.

I tried to find the device/code name for my laptop sound. I found these information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I don't see any codec names in these (if you need any other information, I can provide you same).

---

**Now here's the thing I'm interested in:** If I can somehow determine that *Realtek® ALC892/ALC897 Codec* is same or better than my laptop audio device, it should be OK for me.

**So any way to compare them before I buy this specific motherboard?**

Comment: It looks like your laptop has a Realtek ALC295 chip in it. ALC892/ALC897 is probably better and newer. The people who suggested ALC1200 chips are probably only able to hear the difference with expensive audio equipment. (Like with an amp & large loudspeakers. Or $600 high impedance headphones that *need* a good amp)

Comment: @Romen I saw a video where a youtuber compared some B550 motherboards and said ALC887/897 audio isn't good so he said he would personally choose ALC1200/1220.

Answer (score 0):

For the sound quality, the ALC892 is fine. I have one also and if you are not doing stuff that requires XLR or lots of incoming sounds from microphones, pianos, guitars, or other computers then it is pretty good.

For comparing stuff like audio stuff, watch Youtubers reviewing them.